Is there a way for an entry to be mounted with `mount -a`, but not at boot?
I have a bunch of NFS entries in /etc/fstab that I want to be mounted when I manually execute mount -a, but I don't want them to be mounted automatically at boot.
Is there a way to do that?

your usage of mount -a hence seems to be a bit questionable!

Could you explain why you want this? there's probably an easy workaround for your problem, which might not involve doing a mount -a.

You're right, my usage of mount -a is questionable, indeed. Regarding the purpose, essentially, I don't need NFS entries all the time—usually, my NFS server is not even turned on when I start my PC. But when I do need NFS, I generally need to use multiple locations at once, or don't really want to think twice about what exact location should I mount.

That sounds like a good job for an automount unit, which gets "automagically" mounted when the first program accesses it

Either systemd-automount or autofs can be used.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2495341 &
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Automount_with_systemd

Not in fstab alone, no. It's either automatic or noauto; -a really just mounts everything except for things that are noauto. And that's exactly the same that happens at boot time.
Now, you're using debian, and that means your system manager daemon happens to be systemd. So, that's nice, because you can define mount units, either in fstab or as proper separate unit files, with dependencies on systemd targets, services, or other mount units. You can probably achieve what you need by coming up with a service or other unit that becomes ready exactly when your condition for when your NFS mounts should be mounted is fulfilled. But you haven't told us what that condition really is – "as soon as I type mount -a" is not a viable condition here. "As soon as I'm connected to a specific network" is, or "as soon as I hit the graphical target", etc.
